# Криво сделал apt-get upgrade в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, apt-get

16.04 LTS, GNOME Shell

Пару дней назад сделал apt-get upgrade, а еще обновил Java (JDK, JRE скачал с офф сайта, ставил тем же apt-get).

После последующего включения вместо окна с приглашением выбрать пользователя и ввести пароль - черный экран.

Ctrl-Alt-F1 не работает.

Есть возможность при загрузке выбрать режим восстановления. Там есть способ попасть в shell. Так что командная строка имеется.

По загугленным форумам пришел к выводу, что может стоит попробовать сделать sudo apt-get -f install .

Для этого сначала пришлось разблокировать ФС для записи командой sudo fsck -Af -M

Потом удалил файлы lock из /var/lib/apt/lists/ , /var/lib/dpkg/lock и /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

В итоге удалось запустить apt-get -f install .

Понятия не имею что произошло, но меня как-то не спасло.

Есть идеи что сделать? Мне посоветовали при помощи find -type f -mtime -2 найти что нового я успел установить и искать в гугле подобные проблемы.

В общем, я как-то плыву, не уверен как поступить, постарался написать все максимально подробно.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: связанный вопрос [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/162075/3712)

Comment: То-есть в текстовую консоль вы попасть не можете? Ctrl-Alt-Fn не работает при любых n ? Если вы все-таки как-то попали в систему - изучите /var/log/messages, /var/log/X.org.log.  возможна какая-то ошибка с драйвером видеокарты.

Comment: Могу, хотя нестабильно. В рид-онли режиме. Но научился из него выходить. Изучу, хотя тут другая проблема - не уверен, что что-то пойму и осознаю как исправить. Надо матчасть учить

Comment: Я несколько раз пытался делать именно upgrade и всегда это кончалось плохо. Мне кажется, что если у Вас каталог /home на отдельном томе, то гораздо безопаснее просто установить новую версию с нуля. Это займёт у Вас 20-30 минут. А искать причины неудачного upgrade можно очень долго...

Comment: @Sergey, автор вопроса использовал команду `apt-get upgrade`, а вы (судя по контексту) говорите про `apt-get dist-upgrade`. а с тем, что в дистрибутиве *ubuntu* и **его** наследниках практически неработоспособен «штатный» `dist-upgrade`, увы, приходится жить. потому *ubuntu* имеет смысл ставить лишь в двух случаях: «поставил и навсегда забыл» и «поставил на несколько часов-дней-недель, максимум месяцев».

Comment: @alexander_barakin Да, Вы правы, я  говорил о своём печальном опыте попыток перехода на следующую версию. Но, мне кажется, что *"smart" conflict resolution system* работает и там и там одинаково по дурацки.